How to navigate from external non angular url to an angular page?
I have an angular application deployed to www.mydomain.com/myapp
From Main page I have route to another page www.mydomain.com/myapp/page2
I have an external website and I want to link to www.mydomain.com/myapp/page2. When user clicks on the link, it goes to www.mydomain.com/myapp/homepage instead.
How to resolve this?

Please share the html code. And also, please go through how to ask question.

From the external page try put an URL with a query parameter for the page to indicate whether to redirect to homepage or not:
www.mydomain.com/myapp/page2?fromExternal=true. 

Then in your page2 component, write a code to check whether the query parameter exist, if so, redirect to homepage.
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
) {}


ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    if (params.fromExternal) {
      this.router.redirect(['/homepage'])
    }
});
}

